# Like the J command in Vim, but take a motion

Tags: vim

I like the `J` command for joining many lines, but don’t like having to count how many lines I want to join. I’d prefer to give a motion. This can be faked with `V{motion}J`; is there a way that doesn’t involve entering visual mode (hence clobbering the `*` register)?

Comment: Or, even better: http://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but I use J when I get too many line breaks inserted from some bad line wrapping. I hold shift and repeatedly tap J watching as it improves. If there are a ton of line joins then I suppose I might hold J.

Comment: you don't want to count, but say that you seem to have to.. you want a gesture, but how do you propose that the gesture count how many Js to do?

Comment: @barlop "How do you propose that the gesture count how many Js to do?" The standard vim way: by giving a motion. e.g. one can `d}` to delete a paragraph, or `d32G` to delete to line 32, etc.; and I would like to `J}` to join a paragraph, or `J32G` to join to line 32, etc.

Comment: Wasn't really saying it didn't belong here, just suggesting it may get a better answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no default join operator. But you can use this code, from [a old vim thread on the same subject](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Join-operator-td3378524.html):

```
nnoremap J :set operatorfunc=Joinoperator<CR>g@
nnoremap gJ :set operatorfunc=GJoinoperator<CR>g@
onoremap J j
func! Joinoperator(submode)
        '[,']join
endfunc
func! GJoinoperator(submode)
        '[,']join!
endfunc
```

Notice that using this snippet it won't be possible to use `J` to join a pair of lines -- it will be necessary to use `Jj` (or `JJ` due to the `omap J j`).

Comment: Perfect, 'operatorfunc' was just what I needed to know about.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
:.,/pattern/join
```

Essentially you're telling Vim to join a range of lines, `.` being the current line the cursor is on, and the last line being the first match of `pattern`.

Comment: You can also mark the end position and use `:.,'bj` to join the ranges. Will need to be at `'a` or vim will ask you to about swapping ranges Or mark start and end and use `;'a,'bj` Use a relative range `:.,+20j` etc